# Extjs4 Dataview disable key navigation

Tags: extjs, extjs4, dataview

I am using "Ext.view.ViewView" for menu. We can select menu item by arrow keys as default feature in extjs "dataview". But i need to menu item select only by click.

Is there are any way to enable selectionChange  for just only click event.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a little old but had same issue and solved by specifing a "selModel" config in my dataview

```
selModel: {
    enableKeyNav: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[enableKeyNav](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.DataViewModel-cfg-enableKeyNav)

in ExtJS 4.1 you can add

```
single: true
```

to your event, and it will be fired only once..

Comment: Thanx, its make some sense.But I need "enableKeyNav" set to "false" when create my view. Currently i am using this               afterrender : function(view){
                view.getSelectionModel().keyNav.disable();
            }